# Creating alert for the aws cloudwatch logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, monitoring, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have a AWS cloudwatch log which have logstreams that contains logs like

```
{"levelname": "INFO", "asctime": "2024-01-27T05:09:56Z+0000", "name": "root", "processName": "MainProcess", "filename": "app.py", "funcName": "lambda_handler", "lineno": 85, "module": "app", "threadName": "MainThread", "message": "reset successful", "aws_request_id": null, "export_rs": true, "user_id": "abcd3928784798ahHBS", "type_of_event": "RESET_SUCCESSFUL", "event_ts": "2024-01-27 05:09:56", "timestamp": "2024-01-27T05:09:56Z+0000"}
```

Here I need to Create an alert when the `user_id` which has more than x times of `type_of_event` RESET_SUCCESSFUL occurances in 6hrs within the mentioned logroup, and the alert message should
contain the `user_id` and the no of occurrences of `type_of_event` ..

I have tried using metric filters for cloudwatch log group, but it filters both user_id and type_of_event and I am not able to count user_id which has more occurrences of type_of_event.

Is there a way to achieve this, Can anyone help me here please?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know metric filters from logs will give "flat" numeric results, no grouping available.
For your need custom metrics are the best fit!
Here is how it can be implemented:

1. Change you app top publish custom metric with standard resolution.
2. Custom metric will send value of 1 as we will count for events.
3. Add dimensions to custom metric: UserId and TypeOfEvent.
4. Go to CloudWatch Alarms and click "Create alarm".
5. Select your custom metric and select metric using "query" where you can filter group timeseries using dimensions. [More on metrics query language](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch-metrics-insights-querylanguage.html)

This is examples of how to post custom metrics via cli: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html, by analogy should be no problem to find out how to do it via SDK.